# Proof: Any integer number is a binary substring of some prime

Tags: prime-numbers, bit-strings

Does there exist a (dis)proof of the following proposition:

> For any positive integer N, there exists a prime P with
> larger number of significant bits than that of N, and N is a binary
> substring of P.

Example:

> Let N = 4 [100 base 2].
> Then we need to find some prime P >= 8 [1000 base 2],
> that would contain N as a substring [100] in binary.  One such P would be 19
> [**100**11 base 2] as it contains [100 base 2] as a substring.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community : "As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking" : no it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n=(n_1...n_k)_2$ ($n$ written is basis $2$), then consider $N=2n+1=(n_1...n_k1)_2$.
For $A=2^{k+2}$, we have that $(A,N)=1$ - since $N$ is odd - then, by [Dirichlet's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), there is a prime number of type $rA+N$ for some integer $r$, and it would contain $n$ as a substring by construction.

Comment: Could you clarify the following: (a) what is $k$ and (b) what does $(A,N)$ mean?

Comment: (a) $k$ is the number of digits of the number $n$ in basis $2$ (and each $n_j$ is a digit). (b) $(A,N)$ is the maximum comom divisor of $A$ and $N$ - it should get clearer if you click on the link directed to Dirichlet's Theorem - please feel free to ask further if it isn't clear yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is clear now, I usually encounter $gcd(A,N)$ type of notation for the greatest common divisor.